# pyinstaller: error: the following arguments are required: scriptname

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable

i am trying to make a simple executable file using pyinstaller. by following the steps given in link blow.

[https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/]

but at step 5 i am getting the error for using command
"pyinstaller --onefile -main"

pyinstaller: error: the following arguments are required: scriptname

my file name is main and it containt only one line 
print("hello world")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although you are making simple executable file of one line code, it is the most simple case. for this you should try this

```
"pyinstaller main.py"
```

the other parameters are used for most complicated code where different libraries are used.
if yet not satisfied just read [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html).

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, you are missing the file name.
try doing it like this.

pyinstaller --onefile main.py

Comment: no it is not working. there is a script name required. and the script name is main.py.

Comment: pyinstaller --onefile main.py

Comment: Are you in the same folder as main.py? If you are not in the same folder you need path to main.py.

Comment: i just solved it. a friend suggested me to try simple command. and it worked.

Comment: Can you share the solution?

Comment: i have already answered it. "pyinstaller main.py". see if you could upvote it so others can find it easily

Answer (score 0):

`pyinstaller --onefile -main.py`

With pyinstaller it is good practice do rename your file to `main.py`. Also if you are using GUI, you will probably want `-w` argument which means without a console.

Comment: i have only single line written in code "print("hello world")" nothing else and i didn't understand whaty do you mean by rename file?

Comment: Your line is written inside of a file, let's say you gave it name `hello_world.py` and when you want to run it from e.g. `cmd` if you are on windows, you will need to navigate to the directory where `hello_world.py` is located then type `python hello_world.py` and it will be executed. Similar with pyinstaller, but first rename `hello_world.py` to `main.py`, now open `cmd` (as administrator to avoid any issues), navigate and type the code from the answer, ofcourse omit -w for obvious reason.